# Passing object as parameter in method

Tags: java, oop, methods

I am trying to run a method which will sum the values from two objects. I'am getting "cannot make a static reference to a non-static method". Here is my code...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Circle obj1 = new Circle(10);
        CircleTwo obj2 = new CircleTwo(20);

        System.out.println(calculateRadiusSum(obj1, obj2));
    }

    public int calculateRadiusSum(Circle r1, CircleTwo r2) {
        int R = r1.radius + r2.radius;
        return R;
    }

}

public class Circle {
    int radius;

    public Circle(int r) {
        r = radius;
    }
}

public class CircleTwo {
    int radius;

    public CircleTwo(int r) {
        r = radius;
    }

}
```

Comment: `calculateRadiusSum` is an instance method. Which instance do you expect it to run against? (Read the error message carefully, and make sure you understand the difference between instance and static methods.)

Comment: I couldn't agree more. The error messages you get back are so comprehensive these days. Why do folk ignore them?

Answer (score 1):

`calculateRadiusSum` needs to be `static` too since it's not called from an instance of `Main`:

Change the prototype to

`public static int calculateRadiusSum`

Comment: When i make the method static , the result is 0

Comment: That's a separate issue. In your Circle classes (BY THE WAY: ONLY MAKE ONE CLASS AND MAKE TWO INSTANCES OF THE CLASS), you have `r=radius` instead of `radius=r`

Comment: Tnank you.. It works now.